# Logs show CPU usage and total cost - how does that relate to datastore operations cost?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The logs tell me how much a certain request costs

api_cpu_ms=278 cpm_usd=0.009244

Is this cost still accurate with the new billing model?

Can I deduce anything about the number of datastore operations the request used?

Is there any way to know the exact number of read, write and small datastore operations used during a single request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was told about 2 months ago that they do not reflect the new billing model, and I haven't seen any indications that they've been fixed to reflect the new billing model.

You can get the number of operations per request by enabling Appstats in your application.

Comment: 2nd that - the stats in the log are for the old billing model. they're essentially useless now